# how do i convert data table date to a certain string format

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string actionDate = ((DateTime) objActionDescr.GetDataTable().Rows[0]["ActionDate"]).ToString("MM");
```

the error comes out like i have invalid cast. Please help

Comment: What specifically is the error message?

Comment: What error? Sample input? What ouput do you expect?

Comment: What is the type of `ActionDate` in the table?

Comment: If the ActionDate is a valid value, use `Convert.ToDateTime()` instead, but you should check for dbnull first if that is allowed.

Comment: @Mighty Bodaboom Im expecting something like 01 or 05 as number of months

Comment: specific error: Specified cast is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check if value isn't null, and then convert it to whatever format you need. 
Something like this:

```
//first, check if that column contains value
if (!objActionDescr.GetDataTable().Rows[0].IsNull("ActionDate"))
{
    //if value is there, do with it what you need...

    //this will return month name, -> like August
    string actionDateMonth = (Convert.ToDateTime(objActionDescr.GetDataTable().Rows[0]["ActionDate"])).ToString("MM");
    //this will return month number -> like 08
    string actionDateMonthNumber = (Convert.ToDateTime(objActionDescr.GetDataTable().Rows[0]["ActionDate"])).ToString("mm");
    //same as above
    actionDateMonthNumber = (Convert.ToDateTime(objActionDescr.GetDataTable().Rows[0]["ActionDate"])).Month.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanx Nino this is crazy awesome, i dont know how stack overflow works but i know there a points given. how do i give you that

Comment: @Patrick, just mark it as solved. Take a look [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers) :)